# Flask WTForms Integerfield type is text instead of number

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

This is what I have tried:

```
nrkomp = IntegerField('Number',validators=[NumberRange(min=1, max=5, message='Invalid length')])
```

In developer tools, this form input has type text and not number, I have read the docs, but could not find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Your code seems correct. Note that it's actually a text field whose input is later cast into an integer. The input of form fields is generally text.

Comment: Is there a way for me to make its type a number or do I have to live with this?

Comment: As far as I know all such fields (FloatField, IntegerField, DecimalField...) are of type text. In back-end their values are cast into the corresponding number types. If not possible, an error is thrown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use wtforms html5 [fields](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/fields/html5.py) to get html5 input types, and html5 [widgets](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/widgets/html5.py) as their associated widgets.

```
from wtforms import Form
from wtforms.fields import html5 as h5fields
from wtforms.widgets import html5 as h5widgets


class F(Form):

    n1 = h5fields.IntegerField("Number1")
    n2 = h5fields.IntegerField(
        "Number2", widget=h5widgets.NumberInput(min=0, max=100, step=10)
    )


for f in F():
    print(f)
```

```
<input id="n1" name="n1" step="1" type="number" value="">
<input id="n2" max="100" min="0" name="n2" step="10" type="number" value="">
```