# Flask wtforms Integerfield() returning NaN

Tags: javascript, python, counter, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Can someone explain IntegerField() to me? I have searched everywhere and haven't found a good example for what I am looking for. I have a counter on my website; the up-arrow adds 1, the down-arrow subtracts 1. However, when I click either arrow, it just returns NaN, and it wont update. Any ideas?

**wtform:**

```
class BetaForm(FlaskForm):
    streak = IntegerField('Streak')
    total = IntegerField('Total')
    submit = SubmitField('Update')
```

**Route**

```
def beta():
    form = BetaForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.streak = form.streak.data
        current_user.total = form.total.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been updated!', 'success')
    return render_template('betaone.html', form=form)
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
   <p class="col-12 font100" id="streakcounter">{{ form.streak }}</p>
   <button id="betabuttonplus" onclick="addStreak()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>

<form method="POST" action=""> 
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.submit(class="my-button btn btn-outline-info") }}
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function addStreak() {
    var streak = document.getElementById("streakcounter").innerHTML;
    streak++;
    document.getElementById("streakcounter").innerHTML = streak;
}
```

Comment: Is the up arrow/down arrow behaviour something you have implemented via javascript?  `IntegerField` generates a text input so I wouldn't expect that kind of feature

Comment: @snakecharmerb - this can be [implemented by the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

Comment: Any reason why have you set enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: @pjcunningham yes, but for `type="number"`, no?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm looking at the Mozilla page I linked to and they have an example `<input id="number" type="number" value="42">` and  I see and can use up and down arrows to inc/dec the value.

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes i did implement it with JS and when I set a value instead of {{form.streak}} it works fine, but it wont update obviously because there wouldnt be a POST. Also, why would integerfield generate a text input? I thought the whole point is that it would output a number not a string

Comment: @pjcunningham honestly, i copied and pasted from a different form i have that does work when i hit update. I followed a youtube tutorial for this. However, upon further research, the reason it is on the other form is because there is a file upload, so no reason to have it here... thanks for the catch!

Comment: (1) `IntegerField` generates `<input type="text">`, probably because it predates HTML5;  for `<input type="number">`you need a `NumberField` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459954/5320906) (2) If this still doesn't work after switching to a `NumberField`, we probably need to see the JS (and the body of the POST request, if there is one).

Comment: (Also, if you use a `NumberField`, the up/down arrows should be generated by the browser, as pjcunningham commented - so no JS required to generate them).

Comment: @snakecharmerb let me know if i am missing something, but i looked at WTForms documentation and there isn't a ```NumberField``` option?  Also, I just added the POST request from the html, as well as the JS! Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong - the html5 input is _also_ called `IntegerField` - my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in javascript:

```javascript
document.getElementById("streakcounter").innerHTML
```

retrieves the entire `input` element, but we only want to update its `value` attribute.  This function will update the value correctly:

```javascript
function addStreak() {
    document.getElementById("streak").value++;
}
```

It's possible to avoid having to use javascript to update the form by using an html5 `type="number"` input; modern browsers will automatically provide up and down arrows ("spinners") to update the value.  WTForms provides these inputs in its html5 modules.

```python3
from wtforms import Form
from wtforms.fields import html5 as h5fields
from wtforms.widgets import html5 as h5widgets

class MyForm(Form):
    foo = h5fields.IntegerField('foo')
    bar = h5fields.IntegerField('bar', widget=h5widgets.NumberInput(min=1, max=1000, step=5))

form = MyForm()
for f in form:print(f)

<input id="foo" name="foo" step="1" type="number" value="">
<input id="bar" max="1000" min="1" name="bar" step="5" type="number" value="">
```

Comment: I'd expect the update button to have `type="button"` and for the `streak` input to be inside the `form`, but maybe the html in the question works for you.

Comment: Thank you SO much! I think I will try both of these out; however, I will probably use the first approach, as I want to have customized "spinners". Regardless, I will give these a go later and see! But thank you, I have been stuck on this for so long now

Comment: Update: it worked! Now the only issue is it won't update when I hit the update button. Any quick thoughts?

Comment: We should probably be clear on our terms: in my answer and comment, by "update button" I mean the button that updates the input.  The button that sends the form to the server is the "submit button".  Which button are you referring to?

Comment: You should open a new question: you'll need to know whether the browser sends the post request - check the network tab in your browsers developer tools, and the console tab for JS errors- and whether the server handles it - add a `print()` statement in the `if` block, and an `else:print(form.errors)` to catch any form validation errors.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thank you for all of your help, it has been super helpful!!

Comment: in case you were wondering, I figured it out!:) my form tag was not encompassing the actual buttons, so it was basically updating nothing.  Idid look at the dev tools for network, and I am starting to understand it a little more (first time actually trying to look at it)